# session_set_start_handler throwing warnings

Tags: php, session, session-state, aerospike

I am writing my own session handler as below to make `Aerospike` as the session manager. However, it is throwing warnings about session handler.

`Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler '' - session startup failed in /var/www/session.php on line 165`

I have set the values of `session.save_path` and `session.save_handler` to `""` in `php.ini` as I want to manage the session data storage and retrieval myself with the below class.

**NOTE:** I can use the default aerospike session handling but it saves session data as bytes(hexadecimal format), I can't use it as it is as other applications need to read this data as well, so I am trying to save data as a json encoded string.

A weird behavior is that the `close` method always gets called at script shutdown even though the `session_set_save_handler`'s return value is false!

This works sometimes without error and sometimes throws a warning shown above. Not sure what is missing.

Code:

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );

define('SESS_ID', '66ac548234f96b48b42e18b2d3d7b73a3f1aceb01fa4c20647d3dcaa055b5099');

class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {
    private $database = null;
    private $recordKey = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->init();
    }

    private function init() {
        $this->database = new \Aerospike(
            [
                "hosts" => [
                    0 => [
                        "addr" => "IP_HERE",
                        "port" => 3000
                    ]
                ]
            ], false);
        $this->recordKey = $this->database->initKey( 'cache', 'data', SESS_ID);
    }

    private function isConnected() : bool {
        return ( $this->database instanceof \Aerospike ) && $this->database->isConnected();
    }

    public function open($savepath = '', $id = ''){
        // If successful

        if( is_null($this->database) ) {
            $this->init();
        }

        $status = $this->database->get($this->recordKey, $data);

        if ($status == \Aerospike::OK) {
            $data = json_decode($data['bins']['PHP_SESSION'], 1);

            if( !is_array($data) ) {
                $data = [];
            }
        } else {
            $data = [];
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        if( is_null($this->database) ) {
            $this->init();
        }

        $status = $this->database->get($this->recordKey, $data);

        if ($status == \Aerospike::OK) {
            $data = json_decode($data['bins']['PHP_SESSION'], 1);

            if( !is_array($data) ) {
                $data = [];
            }
        } else {
            $data = [];
        }

        $_SESSION = $data;

        return json_encode($data);
    }

    public function write($id, $dataNode)
    {
        if( is_null($this->database) ) {
            $this->init();
        }

        $data = false;

        if( $this->isConnected() ) {
            $bins = [
                "PHP_SESSION" => json_encode($_SESSION)
            ];

            $status = $this->database->put( $this->recordKey, $bins );

            if ($status == \Aerospike::OK) {
                $data = true;
            } else {
                // error while saving data, log it
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $removeStatus = false;

        if( $this->isConnected() ) {
            $status = $this->database->remove( $this->recordKey );

            if ($status == \Aerospike::OK) {
                $removeStatus = true;
            } else {
                // error while saving data, log it
            }
        }

        return $removeStatus;
    }

    public function close(){
        // Close the database connection
        if($this->isConnected() && $this->database->close()){
            // Return True
            return true;
        }
        // Return False
        return false;
    }

    public function gc($max)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

}

$s = new MySessionHandler();

// Set handler to overide SESSION
$newSession = session_set_save_handler($s, true);

var_dump($newSession); // this returns false sometimes and throws a warning

register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

session_id(SESS_ID);
session_start();

$_SESSION['dfc'] = 'xdc1';
//unset($_SESSION['dfc']);

pr($_SESSION);

unset($s);

function pr($data) {
    if( is_object($data) ) {
       // $data = serialize($data);
    }

    echo '<pre>' . var_export($data, 1) . '</pre>';
}
```

These warnings are thrown intermittently and I am not sure what might be causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP client for Aerospike comes with a [session handler](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/tree/master/doc#aerospike-session-handler). Set `session.save_handler=aerospike`.  See the [`php.ini` options](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/php/classes/Aerospike.html) of the module.

If you're writing your own session handler

- Don't set `session.save_handler=''`. You want to comment it out in your php.ini instead, because that gets loaded and executed first (before your script) and it's non-sensical. There is no such handler. That should suppress the warning.
- Watch out for null bytes. PHP strings can have those in the middle, but Aerospike strings will terminate there, so it'll get truncated at that point. Read the documentation on [Handling Unsupported Types](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/tree/master/doc#handling-unsupported-types), which is why you're provided the [`\Aerospike\Bytes`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/php/classes/Aerospike.Bytes.html) wrapper class.

Comment: I have disabled `save_handler` in php.ini itself and am not trying to set it in the code. Still getting those warnings sporadically.

Comment: That warning isn't an Aerospike client warning. Also, there's a difference between request lifecycle and process lifecycle, which is why the PHP session handler that comes with the Aerospike module is more efficient. You don't want it opening and closing connections on every request.

Comment: Agreed on that. I fixed it by setting `session.save_handler=files` in `php.ini`. However, I was using a custom session handler as given above so I could use any handler as desired thus bypassing the ini setting. Working fine now. Thanks!